# Can azure CLI get a list of all resources running in a tenant?

Tags: powershell, azure

Is there a single command way to get all the resources in a tenant dumped out in JSON format, either in az cli or powershell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/resource?view=azure-cli-latest#az-resource-list)

```
az resource list
```

[Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/get-azurermresource?view=azurermps-5.7.0)

```
Get-AzureRmResource
```

Comment: This only lists the resources for the current **subscription**.  You'll have to loop through all the subs in the tenant and run `az resource list` to see all resources

Answer (score 4):

The code below will loop through all subscriptions and output all resources to a CSV file in the current directory.

```powershell
$accountList = az account list
$accountObjectList = $accountList | ConvertFrom-Json
$accountObjectList | ForEach-Object -Process {
               $subscriptionId = $_.id
               $subscriptionName = $_.name
               az account set --subscription $_.id
               $resourceList = az resource list --output json --query "[].{name:name, resourceGroup:resourceGroup, type:type, sku:sku.name, kind:kind, location:location }"
               $resourceObjectList = $resourceList | ConvertFrom-Json
               $resourceObjectList | ForEach-Object -Process {
                         $_ | Add-Member -NotePropertyName SubscriptionId -NotePropertyValue $subscriptionId
                         $_ | Add-Member -NotePropertyName SubscriptionName -NotePropertyValue $subscriptionName

               }
               $resourceObjectList | Export-Csv -Path .\azureResourceList.csv -Append
}
```